# how to install a responsive package in react.js

Tags: reactjs, responsive

I tried to install fit.js on React, but I end up with the following error

> cannot resolve fit.js in App.js

Yet, I imported my fit into Apps js like this:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import fit from 'fit.js'
```

And then used it like:

```js
function App() {

    useEffect(() => {
        fit(document.querySelector('# root'), document.querySelector('body'), {
            watch: true
        });
    }, []);

}
```

I installed fit in my my-app like this:

> npm i fit.js

Some help ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no official package of fit.js in npm. So paste this link in index.html in public folder, then use

https://rawgithub.com/soulwire/fit.js/master/fit.js

**Edit**

paste this in html

```
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/soulwire/fit.js/master/fit.js"></script>
```

Comment: Specifically in a script tag: `<script src="https://rawgithub.com/soulwire/fit.js/master/fit.js"></script>`